# Unable to load stylesheet via wp_enqueue_style

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I am using this

```
<?php// Load the theme stylesheets
function theme_styles() { 

    // Load all of the styles that need to appear on all pages
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
?>
```

to add a stylesheet in my theme, but it's not loading the stylesheet

Comment: Are you using a parent theme or a child theme

Comment: i Am developing my Own Theme.

Btw what is meant by parent and child theme ?

Comment: Check [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: No i am not using any child theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo have not opened the `php` tag correctly in the beginning of your snippet. try adding at least one space after `<?php` and right before the first `//`:

```
<?php // Load the theme stylesheets
    function theme_styles() { 

    // Load all of the styles that need to appear on all pages
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
?>
```